# problem in upload image and insert to post

Tags: wordpress

i have a problem in putting image in my post, i could upload image on add new post (add pcture) , but when i click to insert to post button , it comes blank page

how may i fix this problem?

it works fine on localhost but i have this problem on my server

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can view it in the gallery, but when insert into post nothing shows in the editor ?

try linking to an image from another website and try writing the code to the image yourself to see if problem from images on ur hosting / from theme ... aka some troubleshooting

Comment: yes , i can see image in the gallary, also i can see picture in the post when i use of link

Comment: try using the editor in full mode and check if you can now see the pic - otherwise - are you on a slow connection ?

Answer (score 0):

Check Your function.php file(rename it) and than check its working.then you have problem in function.php i solved my problem through this may be useful to you.